# Bind a combobox to another dataset than the datacontext in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, c#-4.0

Let me explain my challenge. I have a dataset with a datatable that is assigned to the datacontext. One of the fields is a category. All the category names are in another datatable (one to many relationship).

I want the combobox to display all the names in the categories datatable with the correct selected value from the datacontext datatable. So if I change category, datatable1 will be updated with the selectedValue from the combobox.

I read something about a ObjectDataProvider, but I didnt get it to work. How can I manage to get this to work?

Comment: You should post your attempt to get it to work, so that people can see a specific problem you're dealing with.  Your question is too vague to collect many useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="ButtonEffects.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300" Name="uc">
    <Grid>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uc,Path=Categories}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" SelectedValuePath="Id" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCategoryId}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Categories being a property in you codebehind.The itemsouce will be populated from the categories table and your selectedvalue will be updated in your datacontext datatable.Hope this helps

**EDIT**

If your datacontext is a dataset then the selectedvalue should be like

```
SelectedValue="{Binding datatable1/SelectedCategoryId}"
```

Comment: If I understand you correct. The categories datatable should be stored in a codebehind property, while I continue to use the regular dataset in the datacontext?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't get the ItemsSource binding to work, but I created a ObjectDataProvider and assigned the dataset to that provider. And then set the ItemsSource to the objectdataprovider. Thanks for the help!